# Custom Form Does Not Display "Created By" value

Tags: custom-form

I'm creating a custom form in SharePoint designer and I'd like to display the value of the "Created By" field in a section of the form. I've done this successfully with other columns in the form.

For example, in SPDesigner, I selected the "Title" field and changed the "Format As" value to "Text". As a result, SPDesigner updated the HTML code to look like this: `<xsl:value-of select="@Title" />`. The result is that the Title field value is displayed (not editable) in the form.

However, when I try to use the code `<xsl:value-of select="@Created_x0020_By" />` to display the name of the person who created the list item - nothing displays in this location on the form.

Can anyone tell me how I can display the list item creator's name in my custom form?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is the way it works for me:

```
<tr>
    <td valign="top" class="ms-formlabel"><nobr>Created by</nobr></td>
    <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
        <SharePoint:CreatedModifiedInfo ControlMode="Display" runat="server">
        <CustomTemplate>
            <SharePoint:FormField FieldName="Author" runat="server" ControlMode="Display" DisableInputFieldLabel="true" /><br/>
            <SharePoint:FieldValue FieldName="Modified" runat="server" ControlMode="Display" DisableInputFieldLabel="true"/>
        </CustomTemplate>
        </SharePoint:CreatedModifiedInfo>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `<xsl:value-of select="@Author" />` instead.

Comment: I think that's a great suggestion - but it does not work.

Comment: That should do it, Author is the internal field name for the Created By column.  Something else to try would be to put it on the form as an editable field, then change the layout of the input field to text.

Comment: Unfortunately, your solution does not work. Please note that I'm dealing with a custom list - not a document library or standard list. This custom list was created based on the Item template and additional fields have been added.

Comment: This is a custom edit form you're trying to make I take it based off of inserting a Custom List Form web part?

Comment: Yeah. I've got a custom list created in SharePoint. I opened this list in SharePoint Designer and created a new custom edit form. In the custom form, I first changed the Title field to be a text field. Then I copied the table row that the Title existed in, pasted it just below row with the Title field, and changed the field name in the <xsl:value-of> function to "@Author". I would expect this to work as well - but my form is still showing blank (while the SharePoint:CreatedModifiedInfo control still shows the proper information at the bottom of the page).

Comment: Reviewing some previous pages of mine, I have done this, the only difference is that it was on a page where I inserted the custom form via the Data View option and specified it as a form, I can then use <xsl:value-of select="@Author" disable-output-escaping="yes" /> to show the Created By person. Now to find out what the difference is between the custom list form and data view form.

Comment: Using the @Author attribute won't work. You need to use the Sharepoint CreatedModifiedInfo control (see my answer)

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar kind of issue in development. My requirement was to make custom edit form and disable a few fields if the logged in user and the created by of the account was same. I tried retrieving the @Author value using  but it always displayed null.

So found a very good solution on it.
In designer find the line

Change the ListItem To List. With this you will get all the fields of the list including @Author , @Editor ,@Created and @Modified.

The only issue is you will all the items , so u will have to filter the item based on the id that we get in the querystring