# Modified By value on form SharePoint(No Code)

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have created a custom list with 3 columns, when I add a edit an item of this list I can see created by and modified by details at the end of the form. I want to display just modified by value at some other place in the same form. I am able to display modified date using formula [Modified], but not able to get modified by. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Internal name of field Modified By is Editor. Did you try to  use [Editor] in your formula? (since [Modified] is working)

Comment: Does not work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem you did with the "Modified By" (@Editor) field not showing up on my customized edit form. Following the example from [this post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/21202/custom-form-does-not-display-created-by-value), I was able to get the "Modified By" value to display on my edit form by adding the following markup:

```
<SharePoint:CreatedModifiedInfo ControlMode="Display" runat="server">
    <CustomTemplate>
        <SharePoint:FieldValue FieldName="Editor" runat="server" ControlMode="Display" DisableInputFieldLabel="true"/>
    </CustomTemplate>
</SharePoint:CreatedModifiedInfo>
```

Comment: I am sorry, but i could not find related to my problem in this article, could you please point it out. Tried <xsl:value-of select="@Modified_x0020_By"/> but did not work. :(

Comment: You are correct. I was testing this against a document library and not a custom list. I have it working now and will edit this answer.

Comment: Hi Danny, I have a new requirement where I have to show item creator's name instead of modifier, I have tried to replace Editor with Creator but did not work. Please help.

Comment: Worked with Author. :)

Answer (score 1):

In the ribbon click on the tab "List" > "Modify View"

Then you need to check this option "Modified By" field and save the view. Please refer to the sample view screen below
[image]

Comment: I can display it in view..but i need it on the form.