# Using SharePoint:FormField to dislay site columns inside my Publishing PageLayout

Tags: sharepoint-designer, page-layout, publishing-site, enterprise-wiki

I want to add additional fields to my enterprisewiki.aspx page layout, these fields are :-

- created
- created by
- version

so i try editing the page layout inside SharePoint designer, but i can not find a reference for these columns inside the columns toolbox. so i try finding how the following default message is constructed,:-

[image]

and i find the following default code :-

```
<SharePoint:FormattedString FormatText="<%$Resources:wss,wikidiff_lastmodifiedby%>" runat="server">
                        <SharePoint:FormField id="modifiedFieldCtrl" ControlMode="Display" FieldName="Modified" runat="server"/>
                        <SharePoint:UserField id="editorFieldCtrl" ControlMode="Display" FieldName="Editor" runat="server"/>
                     </SharePoint:FormattedString>
```

so i change the above default code to be as follow, and i  get the Created date field:-

```
<SharePoint:FormField id="createdFieldCtrl" ControlMode="Display" FieldName="Created" runat="server"/>
```

so my question is how i can follow the same approach to display the Created BY & version values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following:

```
   <SharePoint:UserField id="modifiedFieldCtrl" ControlMode="Display" FieldName="Author" runat="server"/>
            <SharePoint:FieldValue FieldName="Version" runat="server" ControlMode="Display" DisableInputFieldLabel="true"/>
```

[Custom Form Does Not Display "Created By" value](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/21202/custom-form-does-not-display-created-by-value)

Comment: thanks a lot for the great help , finally i got these working. but my question now is why these fields are not available in the "Page fields" or inside the "control fields" toolbox inside the SharePoint designer ?

Comment: No idea about that. You can ask a fresh question for this, so that somebody else can help on this better.