# Custom Form Does Not Display “Name” value

Tags: 2010, document-library, custom-form, internal-name

I created a custom `EditForm` for my document library and the field `Name` that containing the document name is not showing up. How to insert it in my form ?

[This article](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/21202/custom-form-does-not-display-created-by-value) is talking about a similar issue with the `Created By` field.

I also read solutions talking about "__designer:bind" and they are  not working for me. I got the following error message:

> ...does not contains TestDeviceFilter definition and no extension method 'testDeviceFilter' with argument...

Finaly I searched for a column named `Name` inside my document library definition and I wasn't able to find it, (actually there are several columns named "Name" but they aren't relevant).

Comment: Can you try with Title of the document instead of Name ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. I tried with the title of the document and I got it. But what I want is the name of the document.

Answer (score 2):

I added the following snippet:

```
<td class="ms-formbody">
  <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" ID="field_name" controlMode="Edit" FieldName="Name" />                                 
</td>
```

I don't know why but the FieldName attribute should be the exact displayed name (and NOT the internal name) of the column we want to display.